# Capture all warnings that occur during execution

Tags: matlab, warnings

After executing a script I try to read the warning state via

```
matlab_warnings = warning;
```

The point is, not all warnings that occurred during execution are inside this warning state. When calling

```
warning('on', 'verbose');
```

I get a useful hint on how to disable a specific warning, however, I'm still curious why some warnings wont appear in `warning`. In my case I'm calling `quadprog` and this function (part of the Optimization Toolbox) throws the warnings I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, `lastwarn` acutally contains one of the warnings I'm looking for. Why isn't `lastwarn` in sync with the last entry of `warning`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`warning` does not return the warnings which occurred in your code, instead it returns the setting if a warning should be displayed or not. `lastwarn` is the only way to access warnings and it only allows access to the most recent warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which parts of your code are probable to generate warnings, you could append `lastwarn` to a list each time after you execute your code. Code snippet below.

```
warnlist=[];
while somecondition
    % Code that might generate a warning, eg your 'quadprog' function call.
    warnlist = [warnlist; lastwarn]
    warning('') % Clear the last warning, so you wont get dupes in the list
end
```